# Adding a legend to the ggplot map with shape

Tags: r, google-maps, legend, ggmap

I have used two layers geom_point, with shape 24 and default. I would like to represent shapes and respective description in the legend. Can any one guide me how to do it.

```
total_map<-ggmap(Map)+
geom_point(data = crime_poss_drugs,shape=24,size=6,
aes(x = lon, y = lat,colour=factor(drug_cases)))+
geom_point(data = crime_prod_drugs,aes(x = lon, y = lat,colour=factor(drug_cases)))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can put `shape=...` into the call to `aes(...)`.

```
library(ggplot2)
# make up some data
set.seed(1)
crime_poss_drugs <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10,1), drug_cases=rep(1:2,each=5))
crime_prod_drugs <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10,3), drug_cases=rep(1:2,each=5))
# plot with different shape for each dataset
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=crime_poss_drugs, 
             aes(x, y, color=factor(drug_cases), shape="POSS"))+
  geom_point(data=crime_prod_drugs, 
             aes(x, y, color=factor(drug_cases), shape="PROD"),size=3)+
  scale_shape_manual("Crime",values=c(POSS=24,PROD=16))+
  scale_color_discrete("Drug Cases")
```

[image]